# Entity Framework setup on mac

Tags: c#, macos, entity-framework

I have worked with entity framework on my job computer in windows. And when you install EF from visual studio, it just runs, no need to edit any config files.

So I want to try this on my mac computer as well, but when I install EF nothing is put in the Web.config file of my project. I tried following microsoft guides and inserting

```
 <section name="entityFramework" 
 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

Also I have tried to copy in the connection string to my localhost

```
<connectionStrings> 
<add name="TestConnection"  
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  
   connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Blogging;Integrated Security=True;"/>
```

I have tried changing the server to localhost:3306, (LocalDB)\SQLEXPRESS, .\SQLEXPRESS and dozens of other tries. But everytime I just get the error:

System.NetSockets.SocketException -> Could not resolve host '.'

Has anyone experienced any problems with installing and running EF on their mac computer?

Regards

Comment: Have you referenced EF NuGet package? Are you running on .NET Core or Mono?

Comment: Yes the package is there. It is not core, so might be mono?